# Does unregisterised mode requirement prevent Haskell's basic FFI examples in normal cases?

Tags: c, haskell, code-generation, ffi

From the [Haskell Wiki page about calling Haskell function from C](https://wiki.haskell.org/Calling_Haskell_from_C), there is a nice short example that I am trying to reproduce, which boils down to compiling some Haskell code that uses the C FFI with command line options such as:

`ghc -c -O Safe.hs`

One point of note is that in the Haskell Wiki page, the compiler option used is actually `-c` (lower case) and this does not generate the intermediate C code, so it is likely a typo.

However, as I discovered when trying to compile with the `-C` option (the option that is documented as emitting intermediate C code), this is unavailable unless you build GHC in "unregisterised mode" which essentially drops GHC's native code generator and leaves only a very basic C code generator (what is used for these FFI examples) and the more highly optimized LLVM-based code generator.

In fact, [from some documentation about GHC](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/code-generators.html), it suggests that you can *only* use the `-C` option in unregisterised mode.

Is it true that you must build GHC in unregisterised mode in order to generate intermediate C code (via the `-C` option)?

If this is true, doesn't it imply that you can't follow these instructions to call Haskell code from C code in almost any situation (since building in unregisterised mode is generally undesirable and very uncommon)?

In my case, I have actually a Python library and some project constraints that imply the code must be callable from Python, but which can benefit greatly from writing a lot of it in Haskell and using Haskell functions.

My goal is to create an extension module for Python, which is very easy to do using Cython with C source. So if I can create the Haskell-from-C source and compile it to a library, it will be pretty easy to call from Python. Then I can worry about how to generate that wrapper code automatically.

But if it requires this very specialized way of building GHC, it won't be useful to anyone who needs to work with it later, because they probably won't have that specialized build and won't want to fuss with it.

Such a simple FFI capability (the C code generation part) seems like something that should "just work" in the most vanilla of builds of any Haskell compiler, at least to me.

Comment: From what I can tell, that whole FFI is based around compile-time C code generation. Basically it's just making your Haskell code generate C code that is directly callable from C, so you inevitably have to use that older C code generator. You might have better luck if you want to avoid this to build a shared library with native Haskell that you communicate with from your C Python extension module, then import the Python extension module. So Python talks to a C dylib which talks to your Haskell dylib.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, I believe that is already what I am trying to do. But the question is how to compile-then-include-and-use the Haskell code in the C code that will just wrap it and be compiled to a dynamic library for purposes of existing as a Python extension.

Comment: In other words, what compilation steps are recommended to treat the source Haskell code that uses Foreign.C.Types? From that Wiki page I thought it was precisely this step of using `-C` to get C code (then I would make that C code a library rather than an executable as the Wiki example does), and then whatever else you want to do with it (Python stuff in my case).

Comment: It's a bit different from what I can tell. That Haskell FFI seems to generate C code (header and source) along with object code to statically link to your C project. The shared library solution would have you create a Haskell dylib (aka shared library) as an independent project from your C project (so you don't need C code generation). The C project would then do symbol lookups into your Haskell dylib, dynamically linking to it at runtime and getting function pointers out of it, and call functions that way.

Comment: It's a bit more manual on the C side if you build Haskell shared libraries (dylibs/DLLs) this way as you'll have to write more code there to load your Haskell library, lookup symbols from it, and fetch function pointers out, and requires you to distribute an additional binary file with your software, but I think it'll give you much more peace of mind that trying to use that C-code-generating FFI. https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2014.2.0.0/ghc/users_guide/using-shared-libs.html

Comment: I see, you are suggesting something [like this](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/so.xhtml). I'll certainly give it a look.

Comment: Yes, very much so. I'm coming at this more from a C side, but that FFI seems more like a neat trick exploiting a legacy artifact of GHC that originally generated C code (not uncommon when building compilers to lean on another language this way, but generally not as efficient as skipping the middle man). So you have to marry that old C code generator if you use this FFI. With shared libraries, you have a much wider range of build options, and you can keep your Haskell project more separate/independent from the C Python module (both good and bad, but probably overall better for your case).

Comment: Looks nice! One thing that might be interesting is that you might be able to potentially skip the C module middle man by actually using a _dynamic_ FFI on the Python side which can use your Haskell shared libraries directly: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/03/09/python-ffi-with-ctypes-and-cffi

Comment: You are right that the middle C module is skippable, but not for that reason (since all of the modules I built were dynamic). I did update the post to reflect just using Cython directly on the Haskell shared library, which is nice. I think it is useful to think of it in terms of that intermediate C module that wraps haskell functions, though. Mainly this is because any non-trivial Haskell functions will eventually require you to deal with the Haskell API and you can't do that directly with Cython. So in such a case, you could write C wrappers that marshal Haskell, then use Cython on that.

Comment: The `cffi` suggestion is great though. I did show an example in my post about why a simple use of `ctypes` is not a safe idea, but perhaps `cffi` takes care of exactly this sort of thing. Anyway, I'm very glad I worked through this from scratch. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: NP -- what I meant is that this `cffi` will do that work of dynamically linking to your Haskell lib for you. ATM the C Python module would dynamically link to Haskell, and Python would dynamically link to the C module (Python->C->Haskell). Without that cffi, Python can only recognize dylib exports that match exactly what it wants, and unfortunately there's no Haskell Python lib (to my knowledge) that allows you to export what Python natively wants from a shared lib. So unfortunately we would normally have to export the symbols Python wants from C...

Comment: With that cffi, you can make Python recognize any dylib-exported functions, not just the ones in the exact form it wants, and can then go straight from Python->Haskell shared lib. On the upside, that C middle man serves as kind of a proxy to wrap things into something a bit more Python-friendly. The `cffi` would allow Python to call functions straight from a dylib (in any form, not just Python API form), and would lose the safety and Pythonesque goodies (unless you add it back on top from Python).

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now -- sorry, the way I said it was confusing. Before you had Haskell->C as a statically-linked process, forcing you to compile Haskell into C.  We eliminated that need with a shared lib. But we still have a C middleman, just as a separate dylib we don't have to bother with when building our now-independent Haskell dylib. But we can take that C project out of the picture completely using Python's cffi, and then you can focus on only working in Haskell and Python as your languages.

Comment: Have you tried just running the commands exactly as they are on that wiki page, with your presumably registerised compiler?

Comment: Yes, if you use "-c" it merely generates the object file, not the C files as needed nor as claimed. In my case, I need the C source files, not just the object files (although I did enjoy learning from the workaround of compiling to a shared library, then possibly including from that library in a separate C file that uses the HsFFI.h API, and *then* wrapping that with Cython).

Comment: Either of two things could fix that wiki article: (1) explaining that you need the unregisterised compiler and the -C option, or (2) explaining that you shouldn't expect (or need, for that article's sake) the .c file and to just use the object file.

Comment: I don't know why you need a .c file... normally the fate of a .c file is to be provided as input to a C compiler; and the C compiler will be just as happy to accept an already-compiled .o file. If Cython won't let you link to a .o file and insists that you provide a .c file plus a shared library, that sounds more like a limitation of Cython. Agreed that the wiki page is inaccurate, but the answer to your titular question is "no" as I described in my answer; there is no unregisterised mode requirement in normal cases.

Comment: Cython is happy to let you link to the .o file. The problem is that you need to provide declarations for the functions you wish to use (from either .o or .so) in Cython (actually, this is a *benefit* of Cython). So if you wanted to invoke Haskell functions that did not *have to* be limited to Foreign.C.Types for their input and output args, then with only the .o or .so file, you need to have an annoying intermediate C file you write yourself that does whatever marshaling you want for the types. If you can get Haskell to give you the C file, though, you can just start directly in Cython.

Comment: Declarations are in the `_stub.h` file.

Comment: Yes, but this too doesn't get created if you use `-c`. Instead, it appears to create a `.hi` file, which as far as I could tell is sort of like a header file, but intended for other Haskell consumers of the compiled code.

Comment: Yes, it does get created, did you try it?

Comment: Yes, for example, right now I typed `main = putStrLn "hello"` into a file named `foo.hs` and then typed `ghc -c foo.hs` and it creates for me `foo.hi` and `foo.o` and nothing else.

Comment: That's because there were no foreign export declarations in your Haskell source...

Comment: Ugh. Even when I did it for my source file that was just copied from the linked wiki page, it was the same (and that did have a foreign export). Just `.hi` and no other header-like files.

Comment: Also, reading about the output into the .h file, it looks a little wonky to me. For example, it looks like if you declared a function of type `:: CInt -> Cint`, the generated header would say actually it is `HsInt32`. I think that's a simple typedef, so likely not too hard to deal with. But for anything that has a Haskell type not directly amenable to a Python foreign C type, you now can't deal with it straight in Cython. You'd need to create a C file, let the C file include from the Haskell library, and wrap the Haskell type so it can be accessed in Python.

Comment: One thing I plan to explore though is what the workflow is like if you do Cython `cdef extern from "HsFFI.h"` and try to define a Python analogue for all of that. It's probably an extremely large and involved project, but could be interesting.

Comment: Try again I guess. It does generate the `Safe_stub.h` file for me (using the example and command copied from the wiki page), and it certainly is supposed to generate it, if it doesn't that's a bug.

Comment: Even if you do have to do some C-side marshalling to match up Haskell's ideas of C's types with Python's ideas of C's types, you wouldn't be any better off if you had C source for the `.o` file, which would be full of even more Haskell-specific types.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need an unregisterised GHC to export Haskell functions to C as described on that Wiki page. There are many specific questions here, so I'll answer them one by one.

> From the Haskell Wiki page about calling Haskell function from C, there is a nice short example that I am trying to reproduce, which boils down to compiling some Haskell code that uses the C FFI with command line options such as:
>
> ```
>  ghc -c -O Safe.hs
> ```
>
> One point of note is that in the Haskell Wiki page, the compiler option used is actually -c (lower case) and this does not generate the intermediate C code, so it is likely a typo.

It's not a typo. `-c` means "compile to an object (`.o`) file", as opposed to the default of "compile to an executable". (The option name matches the name of the same option in C compilers, which is why it makes no particular sense.)

> However, as I discovered when trying to compile with the -C option (the option that is documented as emitting intermediate C code), this is unavailable unless you build GHC in "unregisterised mode" which essentially drops GHC's native code generator and leaves only a very basic C code generator (what is used for these FFI examples) and the more highly optimized LLVM-based code generator.
>
> In fact, from some documentation about GHC, it suggests that you can only use the -C option in unregisterised mode.
>
> Is it true that you must build GHC in unregisterised mode in order to generate intermediate C code (via the -C option)?

Yes, because only an unregisterised compiler compiles via intermediate C code at all. The GHC calling convention (with various global variables pinned to registers) that is used by registerised compilers (hence the name) cannot be expressed in C at all. And, whether a particular build of GHC produces registerised or unregisterised code is a decision that was made at compile time of that build of GHC.

> If this is true, doesn't it imply that you can't follow these instructions to call Haskell code from C code in almost any situation (since building in unregisterised mode is generally undesirable and very uncommon)?

No, because you can call Haskell code that is built by a registerised compiler from C code as well. One of the nice features of C is that it has a relatively standard (per platform) ABI, so a compiler for any language can produce object files that are binary-compatible with C object files, without ever invoking the host C compiler at all.

> In my case, I have actually a Python library and some project constraints that imply the code must be callable from Python, but which can benefit greatly from writing a lot of it in Haskell and using Haskell functions.
>
> My goal is to create an extension module for Python, which is very easy to do using Cython with C source. So if I can create the Haskell-from-C source and compile it to a library, it will be pretty easy to call from Python. Then I can worry about how to generate that wrapper code automatically.
>
> But if it requires this very specialized way of building GHC, it won't be useful to anyone who needs to work with it later, because they probably won't have that specialized build and won't want to fuss with it.
>
> Such a simple FFI capability (the C code generation part) seems like something that should "just work" in the most vanilla of builds of any Haskell compiler, at least to me.

Yes, it does just work with any build of GHC. It just doesn't actually pass through C as an intermediate form; the output of GHC is an object file.

Comment: I don't think you read the wiki article very closely. For example, when I say that the `-c` option is a typo, what I mean is that the wiki article claims that with `-c` you will have a `.c` file, a `.h` file, and a `.o` file generated, such that you can use the functions available in the `.c` and `.h`files as I am describing. But this is false. The `-c` option does not produce these, and crucially it is exactly these `.c` and `.h` files needed in order to do the steps in the wiki, *not* the object file, which doesn't help -- so it has to be a typo.

Comment: That wiki page is partly out of date. There is no `_stub.c` file any more, you just link with the `.o` file. Note that the subsequent steps on the wiki already do not refer to the `_stub.c` file.